# Apache Camel Thread JDBC

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, apache-camel, spring-jdbc

I have a query JDBC that has `168570`, I use a split with multithreading, when I launch the app I have a different number result, anyone can tell me where I am wrong?

```
<from uri="start" />
<to uri="jdbc:dsDB" />
<split>
<simple>$body</simple>
<to uri="bean:testProcessor" />
</split>
```

I tried to split `parallelProcessing="true"` and instantiate a `threadPool`:

```
<threadPoolProfile id="outTestThreadPoolProfile" defaultProfile="true" 
    poolSize="1500" 
    maxPoolSize="1500" 
    maxQueueSize="1500"  
    rejectedPolicy="CallerRuns"/>
```

is how a thread finish the job before the split is complete

Comment: Has 168570 what?

Comment: I see 168570 I raise it to 168575. Jokes aside please provide more information in the question.

Comment: 168570 record result from the query, it's a select * from table , query , in the testProcess i do a mapping with a data manipulation and put the result in a bean

Comment: Dont set such a high pool size. It should be down to a reasonable size that is closer to number of CPU cores.

Comment: @ Claus Ibsen , this values is for test, i started from the default values and i have incremented it because  I thought it was the cause of the problem but it is not